# returned non-zero exit status 123

Tags: python

i am write some code that suppose to take permission list from folder and compare the users\group list between this list to another list and if there is a fit between them he write the folder path so file.
this is the code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os, pprint, sys
from sys import argv

script, FILENAME = argv  ##get folder\file
## copy permissions list to temporary file function
def check_per(path):   ##"check_per" copy permission list to string and compares
        test=open('tempG','w')
    dir = 'GroupList'
    output = subprocess.check_output(['cacls', path]).splitlines()
    test.write(output)
    while (True):
        d=readline()
        if not d: break
        d=d[0:len(d)-1:]
        d=str(d)
        while (True):
            line=groups.readline()
            line=line[0:len(line)-1:]
            if not line: break
            temp=d.find(line, 0, len(d))
            if temp!=-1: 
                dest=open(dir+'/'+line+'.txt','a')
                dest.write(path)
                dest.close()
        groups.seek(0)



temp= open('temp.txt','w')  ##temporary folder from sub-folders path list
file=open('folders_list.txt', 'w') ##arrange path in
##making list of all sub folders under the chosen path
temp.write("%s" %[x[0] for x in os.walk(os.path.abspath(FILENAME))])
temp.close()
temp=open('temp.txt', 'r')
##arrange every path in separate line
while (True):
    a=temp.read(1)
    if not a: break
    if a==',':file.write("\n")
    else:file.write(a)
file.close()
file=open('folders_list.txt', 'r')
temp.close()
os.remove('temp.txt') ##remove temp file    
groups=open('GroupList.txt','r') ###open the file that contain the groups list
dir = 'GroupList'
os.mkdir(dir) ##make new dir for groups files
## making text file for every group in new folder "grouplist" 
while(True):          ##make text file for every group
    a=groups.readline()
    if not a:break
    a=a[0:len(a)-1:]+'.txt'
    b=open(dir+'/'+a,'w')
    b.close()
while (True):  ##taking path from folders list and call "check_per" 
    path=file.readline()
    if not path: break
    path=path[0:len(path)-1:]
    check_per(path)
```

when i test the code i get this error message:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['cacls', path]).splitlines()
    File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 586, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cacls', "['D:\\Scripting\\permissi
    on project'"]' returned non-zero exit status 123

any idea?

Comment: What are you expecting `check_output(['cacls', path])` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is saying that the command returns exit status 123, which indicates an error.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx the status 123 indicates

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Perhaps there is a problem with your directory name? There seems to be a space too much.

Comment: when i tried to run the per_check alone in another script on the some folder it work fine. but when i call her in this script i get this message

Comment: Did you check that the path sent to `check_per` is correct? Maybe it gets mangled somehow?

Comment: tnx, that was the problem i should to clean some residues before send to the function